# Adding a body class based on url in address bar

Tags: jquery, squarespace

**Problem**

I want to add `body` classes to two separate types of pages:

1) Pages that match this url: `example.com/shop/`

2) Pages that have anything after `/shop/` in the url: `example.com/shop/asdfjkl, example.com/shop/item-2342, etc.`

---

So far, I've solved the first problem by using this code:

```
  if(window.location.href.match('example.com/shop/')){
    jQuery('body').addClass('shop');
  }
```

However, this also adds the `shop` class to any url that starts with `example.com/shop/` *(refer to problem #2)*

---

**Question**

How can I add a separate `shop-item` class to just the urls that have characters *after* `/shop/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex for that:

```
if( window.location.href.match(new RegExp('example.com/shop/.+')) ) {
    $('body').addClass('shop-item');
} else if (window.location.href.match('example.com/shop/')) {
    $('body').addClass('shop');
}
```